# What does this code mean: new Action(()=>{})

Tags: c#

I found this code:

```
new Action(()=>{})
```

I would like to understand what the code between parenthesis mean

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break this down:

`Action` - this is the type of a function. (Yes, you can treat a function like data);

`() => {}` - This is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). In this case, it defines a function that takes no parameters, returns nothing, and does nothing.

Consider the following code:

```
void Main()
{
   Action action = new Action(doNothing);   

   // Now we can call the function to do nothing
   action();
}

void doNothing()
{
}
```

We could re-write it as

```
void Main()
{
   Action action = new Action(() => {});    

   // Now we can call the function to do nothing
   action();
}
```

It does the same thing.